# Swift - Converting an AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?> value

Tags: ios, c, url, pointers, swift

So far I have this code:

```
var thumbnailErr: NSError?
var thumbnailDictionary: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?> = nil
let getItemSucceeded = url.getPromisedItemResourceValue(thumbnailDictionary, forKey: NSURLThumbnailDictionaryKey, error: &thumbnailErr)
if getItemSucceeded {

}
```

Now I want to turn thumbnailDictionary into a Dictionary or NSDictionary. This is how I do it in Objective-C:

```
BOOL thumbnailSucceeded = [urlFromPath getPromisedItemResourceValue:thumbnailDictionary forKey:NSURLThumbnailDictionaryKey error:&thumbnailErr];
if (thumbnailSucceeded) {
    NSDictionary *dict = (__bridge NSDictionary *)(void *)thumbnailDictionary;
}
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this in Swift. Help?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Got it. Passing in an AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer wasn't necessary.

```
var thumbnailErr: NSError?
var thumbnailDictionary: AnyObject?
let getItemSucceeded = url.getPromisedItemResourceValue(&thumbnailDictionary, forKey: NSURLThumbnailDictionaryKey, error: &thumbnailErr)
if getItemSucceeded {
    let dict = thumbnailDictionary as NSDictionary
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question. I hate it when I find a post with the exact question I have, only for the owner to post "got it, never mind" without explaining their solution